# Is it possible to Query a Mysql database from a field selected from dropdown menu populated from a Query in php

Tags: php

Hello i am new to php and i have tried to find a piece of code that i can use to complete the task i need, i currently have a page with a form set out to view the criteria of a course. also i have a dropdown menu which currently holds all the course codes for the modules i have stored in a database. my problem is when i select a course code i wish to populate the fields in my form to show all the information about the course selected. The code i am trying to get to work is as follows:

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<? include ("dbcon.php") ?>
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['coursecode'])){ 
$Var ='%'; 
} 
else 
{ 
if($_GET['coursecode'] == "ALL"){ 
$Var = '%'; 
} else { 
$Var = $_GET['coursecode']; 
} 
}


echo "<form action=\"newq4.php\" method=\"GET\"> 
<table border=0 cellpadding=5 align=left><tr><td><b>Coursecode</b><br>";

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM module GROUP BY mId"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($res)==0){ 
echo "there is no data in table.."; 
} else 
{ 
echo "<select name=\"coursecode\" id=\"coursecode\"><option value=\"ALL\"> ALL </option>"; 
for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($res);$i++) 
{ 
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
echo"<option value=$row[coursecode]";

if($Var==$row[coursecode]) 
echo " selected"; 
echo ">$row[coursecode]</option>"; 
}
echo "</select>"; 
}
echo "</td><td align=\"left\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"SELECT\" /> 

</td></tr></table></form><br>";

$query = "SELECT * FROM module WHERE coursecode LIKE '$Var' "; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){ 
echo("No modules match your currently selected coursecode. Please try another coursecode!"); 
} ELSE { 
        Coursecode: echo $row['coursecode'];
        Module: echo $row['mName']; 
        echo $row['mCredits'];
        echo $row['TotalContactHours'];
        echo $row['mdescription'];
        echo $row['Syllabus'];
        }
?>
```

however i can only seem to get the last entry from my database any help to fix this problem or a better way of coding this so it works would be grateful

Thanks

Comment: Before you go any farther with this code, read up about [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com) attacks and fix you code to remove the vulnerabilities. You are wide open for an attack.

Answer (score 0):

The main error is in your final query, you're not actually fetching anything from the query, so you're just displaying the LAST row you fetched in the first query.

Some tips:

1) Don't use a for() loop to fetch results from a query result. While loops are far more concise:

```
$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   ...
}
```

2) Add another one of these while loops to your final query, since it's just being executed, but not fetched.

Comment: Thank you Mark B for that advice it works fine now, thanks for the link to the sql injection i am new to php so will check it out

Comment: Hello Marc B my selection box is working fine now i can select any course code and it returns the details of the course which i can echo onto the page. sorry about this i now have a problem of placing the results into the assign section for viewing. here is a snippet of the form and how i am trying to populate

Comment: <table width="60%" border="2" cellpadding="3" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">Module Specification</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="15%"><div align="right"><strong>Code:</strong></div></td>    
    <td width="45%"><? echo $row["coursecode"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right"><strong>Module:</strong></div></td>
    <td><? echo $row["module"]; ?></td>
  </tr>

Comment: Sorry  I am new to this site the code should look like this             <table width="60%" border="2" cellpadding="3" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">Module Specification</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="15%"><div align="right"><strong>Code:</strong></div></td>    
    <td width="45%"><? echo $row["coursecode"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right"><strong>Module:</strong></div></td>
    <td><? echo $row["module"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
  </table>   is there a way to fix this problem Thank You

Comment: I just thought i would let everyone i have fixed this problem thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

For me i would use some javascript(NOTE: i prefer jQuery)
An easy technique would be to do this(going on the assumption that when creating the drop downs, your record also contains the description):

Apart from creating your dropdown options like this `<option value="...">data</option>`, you could add some additional attributes like so:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['coursecode'].'" data-desc="'.$row['description'].'">.....</option>
```

Now you have all your drop down options, next is the javascript part

Let's assume you have included [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) onto your page; and let's also assume that the description of any selected course is to be displayed in a `<div>` called `description` like so:

```
<div id="course-description">&nbsp;</div>
<!--style it how you wish -->
```

With your javascript you could then do this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#id-of-course-drop-down").change(function(){
        var desc = $(this).children("option").filter("selected").attr("data-des");
        //now you have your description text
        $("#course-description").html(desc);
        //display the description of the course
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you, even a little
Have fun!

**NOTE: At least this is more optimal than having to use AJAX to fecch the description on selection of the option :)**

Comment: Thank You for advice i will try using Java as soon as i get a good understanding of php

Comment: Do you mean Javascript (or do you really mean); i don't see the need for Java in this anyways. Best of luck. Don't forget to vote up useful answers... :)